Peace lily green spots growing in pot
I checked on my peace lily and I see these weird yellowish green spots in the soil around it… what are these?? Are they dangerous?? What do I do

Can you tell us the size and perhaps describe them.  Are thy mushy, or firm or woody?

This is either a decay agent like mushrooms that is eating the organic matter in the soil or a slime mold which would be unusual but very cool.
They are both harmless and are there because the soil is moist.
You can gently stir the top of the soil and keep the plant a little drier to reduce or remove them.

@YosefBaskin ammonia is a weed killer and vinegar is not too much different.  Safer to spend a few minutes work aerating the soil
